# Creating a simple, full-width, infinite carousel with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a slider with jquery. I've looked on line if I could use any of the already made plugins, but none could do what I need to.

On a site I'm working on, I have a 1260px container where the content is.

The slider is fullwidth, and in the center is the active slide, and on the sides are previous and next slides that should serve as a previous and next click.

I plan to expand on that slider so that I have thumbnails beneath it, but for now I need to make the slider working.

HTML is (the images are 1260x520px)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Simple Fullwidth Slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="init.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider clearfix" data-autoplay="0" data-items="1" data-easing="linear" data-duration="750" data-height="520">
        <div class=" single_slide" style="height: 520px; background-image: url('image.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
            <div class="slider_text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="single_slide active" style="height: 520px; background-image: url('image.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
            <div class="slider_text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" single_slide" style="height: 520px; background-image: url('image.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
            <div class="slider_text">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class=" single_slide" style="height: 520px; background-image: url('image.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
            <div class="slider_text">
            </div>
        </div>  
        <div class=" single_slide" style="height: 520px; background-image: url('image.jpg'); background-size: cover; background-position: 0% 0%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
            <div class="slider_text">
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Style css is:

```
/***************** Image Slider ****************/

.slider{
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.slider .single_slide{
    float: left;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.15;
    width: 1260px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
}

.slider .single_slide.active{
    opacity: 1;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 800ms ease-in-out;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('.slider').each(function () {
        var $slider = $(this);
        var autoplay = $slider.data("autoplay");
        var items = $slider.data("items");
        var easing = $slider.data("easing");
        var duration = $slider.data("duration");
        var $single_slide = $slider.find('.single_slide');
        var slider_height = $single_slide.css('height', $slider.data('height')+'px');
        var left_offset = ($(window).width()-1260)/2;

        $slider.css({'width' : $single_slide.length*1260+'px', 'left':- 1260+left_offset + 'px'});

        $single_slide.eq(1).addClass('active');

        var $prev = $('.active').prev();
        var $next = $('.active').next();

        function moveLeft() {
            var $a = $('.active');
            $a.removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
            $slider.animate({
                left: parseInt($slider.css('left'), 10) + $single_slide.outerWidth(true),
                easing: easing,
                step: items,
            }, duration, function () {
                $('.single_slide:first').before($('single_slide:last'));
            });
        }

       function moveRight() {
            var $a = $('.active');
            $a.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            $slider.animate({
                left: parseInt($slider.css('left'), 10) - $single_slide.outerWidth(true),
                easing: easing,
                step: items,
            }, duration, function () {
                $('.single_slide:last').after($('single_slide:first'));
            });
        }

        $prev.click(function () {
            moveLeft();
        });

        $next.click(function () {
            moveRight();
        });

        if (autoplay == 1) {
            setInterval(function () {
                moveRight();
            }, duration);
        }

    });

});
```

I've created a [git repository](https://github.com/dingo-d/simple-fullwidth-slider) as well, so you can download the html files.

I'm originally doing this for wordpress, but the workings is the same.

The problem is that it doesn't seem like the appending of the images once you click previous or next images works. Switching of the classes works, but the next and previous images are not changing when you click on them (I've done something similar but the prev/next buttons were fixed elements, so I could just target them all the time, but here they are changing)-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I got to the root of the issue with the previous and next selectors. They got cached once as a variable but were never updated when the `active` class changes to another slide - so the event listeners would stick to the elements that were initially set as siblings of the active slide :

```
var $prev = $('.active').prev();
var $next = $('.active').next();
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work :

```
$('.active').prev().click(function() { ... });
```

But this *almost* does the trick :

```
$('.slider').find($('.single_slide').eq($('.active').index()+2)).click(function() {
  moveLeft();
});

$('.slider').find($('.single_slide').eq($('.active').index()-1)).click(function() {
  moveRight();
});
```

**Update** - made functional and infinite with the `.detach()` method and a delegated event listener :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOoPgZ?editors=001

```
$('.slider').each(function() {

    var slider = $(this);
    var autoplay = slider.data('autoplay');
    var items = slider.data('items');
    var easing = slider.data('easing');
    var duration = slider.data('duration');
    var single_slide = slider.find('.single_slide');
    var slider_height = single_slide.css('height', slider.data('height'));
    var offset = ($(window).width()-1260)/2-1260;

    $.each(single_slide, function(index) {
        if (index == 0) $(this).addClass('img' + single_slide.length);
        else $(this).addClass('img' + index);
    });

    slider.css({'width': single_slide.length*1260, 'left': offset});
    single_slide
    .eq(0).addClass('prev').end()
    .eq(1).addClass('active').end()
    .eq(2).addClass('next');

    function moveLeft() {

        $('.active').removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');

        slider.animate({
            left: slider.position().left+single_slide.outerWidth(true),
            easing: easing,
            step: items
        }, duration, function() {
            $('.single_slide:last').detach().prependTo(slider);
            slider.css('left', offset);
            newNav();
        });
    }

    function moveRight() {

        $('.active').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');

        slider.animate({
            left: slider.position().left-single_slide.outerWidth(true),
            easing: easing,
            step: items
        }, duration, function() {
            $('.single_slide:first').detach().appendTo(slider);
            slider.css('left', offset);
            newNav();
        });
    }

    function newNav() {

        $('.prev').removeClass('prev');
        $('.next').removeClass('next');
        $('.single_slide')
        .eq(0).addClass('prev').end()
        .eq(2).addClass('next');
    }

    $(document).on('click', '.prev', function() {
        moveLeft();
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.next', function() {
        moveRight();
    });

    if (autoplay == 1) {
        setInterval(function() {
            moveRight();
        }, duration);
    }

});
```

I'm sure there's room for some optimisation but it seems to do the trick. Has a  feature to keep track of the images that may not be needed (but it's handy for debugging).

Now for some swipe support. :-D

Comment: Give me a shout when you got it going, if you can. I'd be interested in such a basic slider. B-)

Comment: One easy solution would be to add previous and next 'buttons' that would overlap the part of the not active images (absolutely positioned), and that would solve that problem. But it would be cool to make images previous and next buttons. I'll see what I can do with that.

Comment: I just realized that the 'infinite' smooth sliding could only be possible (in my way) if I would add the same set of slides after the last one every time I'm nearing the end. But that would overload the DOM (not a good solution). I can create a finite slider that I can then move from left to right, but infinite carousel wouldn't work :\

Comment: That (a finite slider) would be the approach I'd usually take myself. But your initial idea definitely has appeal, so I'm not sure I'm ready to give up on it. Lol. Let me revisit the script... and maybe add some swipe support as well. :-)

Comment: Awesome! I was thinking of attaching a previous and next class, and then on each click see where they are, but this is awesome! :)

Comment: Glad to help out, it was an interesting exercise. It's gonna be handy to have a script like this around. I wasn't kidding about the swipe (on the active image) by the way, that wouldn't need too much code. But maybe I'll open a GitHub account (haven't yet) and see if I can contribute a bit further there. Cheers.

Comment: Fell free to, that would be great ^^