# jQuery Slider that fades and slide at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to find a jQuery Slider that fades and slide at the same time but no sucess so far, so I've decided to try and create my own. Well, so far, I've managed to make it slide and barely fade, by barely I mean that in bigger screens it might look like the content is blinking.

This is my **HTML**:

```
<div id="slider">
    <div class="slide">
        <h1>A Phrase</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <h1>A Phrase</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <h1>A Phrase</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my **jQuery**:

```
var slider = $('#slider .slide'),
    winWidth = $(window).width();

slider.css({
    width: winWidth
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    winWidth = $(window).width();
    $(args).css({
        width: winWidth
    });
});

var slideW = slider.width(),
    slidesQty = slider.length,
    sliderFullW = slidesQty * slideW,
    slideMvCheck = winWidth/2;

$('#slider').css({
    width: sliderFullW
});

function cycleSlides(){
    $('#slider').animate({
        left: -winWidth
    }, {duration: 2000, queue: false}).fadeOut(700).fadeIn(2000, function(){
        $('#slider .slide:first-child').appendTo('#slider');
        $('#slider').css({left: 0});
    });

}

var autoSlide = setInterval(function () {
    cycleSlides();
}, 4000);
```

I need help tweaking the code, I've tried a lot of different things in the past two days, I've ran out of ideas and I'm not very good with jQuery.

Comment: Are you trying to change the opacity?  or fade it to the point of being removed from view?

Comment: I think I'll refer to some code that was recently scribbled together before diving into this one : http://stackoverflow.com/a/29722078/3168107.

Comment: @briansol yeah, i'm trying to fade out as the slide slides to the left until it disappears, while making the next slide fade in as it comes to view.

Comment: @Shikkediel from what i could see, this code you linked creates a slider, my code already does that, i just cant seem to make it slide and fade at the same time.
EDIT: Hmmm, it seems the code has some opacity to it when it slide, i will take a look more carefully at the code

Comment: Yeah, it works with a CSS transition like that for the opacity. Give me a shout if it's not close enough to what you're after. I can always have a go at the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I had a crack at it anyway (see comments) and made this from it :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJyBgj?editors=011

```
var gate = $(window);
var slider = $('#slider');
var slide = $('.slide');
var winWidth = gate.width();

slide.css({width: winWidth});

gate.resize(function() {
    winWidth = gate.width();
    slide.css({width: winWidth});
});

var slideW = slide.width(),
slidesQty = slide.length,
sliderFullW = slidesQty*slideW,
slideMvCheck = winWidth/2;

slider.css({width: sliderFullW});

function cycleSlides() {

    $('.slide').eq(0).animate({opacity: 0}, 700);
    $('.slide').eq(1).delay(700).animate({opacity: 1}, 2000);

    slider.animate({left: -winWidth}, 2000, function() {
        $('.slide').eq(0).appendTo(slider);
        slider.css({left: 0});
    });
}

var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
    cycleSlides();
}, 4000);
```

The tricky thing with using a fade is that it will hide the element when opacity is zero, taking it out of (and interfering with) document flow. So I've made it an opacity animation (keeping physical dimensions intact). Hope that's closer to what was intended. Added a bit of CSS to set opacity to all but the first visible slide :

```
.slide:not(:first-of-type) {
opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: This looks nice, but it reached the same result I had. My text is centered (forgot to mention that before), so as the other text is appearing from the right it slightly blinks before reapparing. I still couldn't check the other code you redirected me to, going to do that ASAP

Comment: I see what you mean with the blinking... so I've updated the answer to get rid of that.

Comment: For some reason, this code did not work at my page, probably there is something else in conflict, the second text comes opacity 0, and only the third text appears and the opacity animation does not work like your code. I need to take a look what is conflicting.

Comment: I pasted some previous code into the answer (and later updated) while the script from the pen was a step ahead and should work as expected. The `slide` variable is cached at the start but can't be reused inside `cycleSlides()` because the order of the elements is changing (so `var slide` is 'outdated'). Hope that solves the issue you mentioned.

Comment: It is working now. Thanks for the help, I'm still very new to jQuery :)

Comment: No trouble, it's good practice for myself as well. There's a few minor pitfalls but in general it can be learned quickly - and it's definitely a great tool to work with. B-)